# Xubuntu: Why does my panel no longer show opened programs?

Tags: xubuntu, users, xfce-panel

This happens in only one of my two accounts/profiles/users, specifically my regular user.  My other account, an administrator account, is not affected by this problem.

I'm on Xubuntu 16.04.2
kernel: 4.4.0-67-generic

I first noticed this about a week ago, maybe a bit more.  Applications fail to show up in the panel.  The main problem obviously is when the program(s) is/are minimized, in which case I have to go to Task Manager to close it and that's all I can do.  There is no way to bring it back, to maximize it.  Obviously this is a big problem making this account almost useless.  Simply put I can't minimize programs; if I do I lose them and the data they contain in the ether.  So I have to do everything in the admin account and it is to avoid this that I created the regular account, for security reasons.

I am opened to any suggestion about this problem.  The research I have done has been fruitless so far.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @mook765 :  Success.  Thank you.  Why did you answer in the comments section?  I can't check "accepted answer" and you gave the correct and successful solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login as the user with the problem. Right-click the panel and choose `Panel > Panel Preferences`. This opens the panel-editor. Check in the `Items`-tab if Window Buttons is listed. If it is not listed, click on the `+` to add it ( you will have to scroll through the list though ).